# Passing a pound sign as a value in the query string of a URL, using Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have an input tag and on input it will filter a list of data in a table according to the input value. That value is passed via the query string in the request URL. Typically I get data returned and the table is updated appropriately. However, when searching for the pound sign (#), I am receiving a 500 internal server error. My question is there a known issue with Angular when passing a pound sign in the query string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To pass [reserved characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) in URLs, you need to use percent encoding. For `#`, it's `%23`.

The wikipedia page for [Percent Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) has a nice [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters).

Comment: Not a bad idea, I think I'll try that. Thanks!!

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you! Don't forget to accept the answer if it resolved your question. :)