# lagging with # and & in angular on http request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, url, asp.net-web-api

### Issue with # and & in angular `http.get()` request URL

Kindly first see my code.

**angular service**

```
let versionsearch ="&";
let strweeksearch="#";

this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'GetVersionInfo?vehicleVersion=' + versionsearch + '&structureWeek=' + strweeksearch,
            { withCredentials: true })
            .map(responce => <CoCApiResponse[]>responce.json())
            .catch(error => {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            });
```

**Web API**

```
  [HttpGet]
  public CoCApiResponse GetVersionInfo([FromQuery]string vehicleVersion, [FromQuery]string structureWeek)
        {
            //code
        }
```

---

### Explanations & Questions:

I have a Get method in web API and it have two string parameters. I am just calling that rest service from angular `http` service via query string which passing those parameters . But particularly if am passing the value is `#` or `&` in query string, I am getting these below problem.

**Using `#` :**

*The API URL will break if am passing `#` in query string.*

But I got some idea for this from this discussion : [Passing a pound sign as a value in the query string of a URL, using Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885007/passing-a-pound-sign-as-a-value-in-the-query-string-of-a-url-using-angular)

So I did it for  replace the `#` to `%23` from angular service like
`strweeksearch.replace(/#/g, '%23');`.

---

**Using `&`:**

The API URL will consider it as 3 parameters, like

**apiurl?versionsearch=&&strweeksearch=123455**

*So Web API method parameter `vehicleVersion` is always getting `NULL`.*

---

> How to achieve this? I don't like to replace every special character to  [`reserved characters`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2). I need every special character should be accept in the `http.get()`. How to handle this in **Angular** or  Web API?

Comment: Do you tried to pass parameters using _params_ property of _config_ object passed to .get()? See: [AngularJS API: $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are adding version search in your get() and appending the string with '&' as well, thats the reasing its thinking you are passing 3 params.

```
this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'GetVersionInfo?vehicleVersion=' + versionsearch + 'structureWeek=' + strweeksearch,
            { withCredentials: true })
            .map(responce => <CoCApiResponse[]>responce.json())
            .catch(error => {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            });
```

try removing one!

Answer (score 0):

Use [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) or [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).